# Use the Segoe MDL2 Assets font as an icon for NotifyIcon

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, notifyicon

Is it possible to use the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font as an icon for a SystemTray app (NotifyIcon)?

I tried using [an answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379547/writing-text-to-the-system-tray-instead-of-an-icon) but it did not work:

[image: but it did not work]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the right [Unicode Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) of the required glyph.

Please consider the following snippet:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Text;

//...

public enum Glyphs
{
    GlobalNavigationButton = 0xE700,
    Wifi = 0xE701,
    Bluetooth = 0xE702,
    Connect = 0xE703,
    InternetSharing = 0xE704,
    VPN = 0xE705,
    //Add more...
}

//...

public static Icon CreateGlyphIcon(Glyphs glyph)
{
    using (var b = new Bitmap(16, 16))
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
    using (var f = new Font("Segoe MDL2 Assets", 12, FontStyle.Regular))
    using (var sf = new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center })
    {
        g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
        g.DrawString(((char)glyph).ToString(), f, Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16), sf);

        return Icon.FromHandle(b.GetHicon());
    }                   
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var icon = CreateGlyphIcon(Glyphs.Connect);

//or

var icon = CreateGlyphIcon(Glyphs.Bluetooth);

//...etc.
```