# Writing text to the system tray instead of an icon and show text of 9 characters in the system tray

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create a windows forms application where I want to show some text dynamically on the system tray instead of the application icon. I used the below code to create a bit map image from the text which will be used to show in system tray. But the space is not suffiecient to show 8 to 9 characters. How to create the space for 9 characters in system tray and show that ico image created from bitmap in that system tray space.

```
// Create a Bitmap and draw the text on it
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
{
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    g.DrawString(newText, new Font("Arial", 8), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}

// Convert the Bitmap to an Icon
Icon customIcon = Icon.FromHandle(bitmap.GetHicon());

// Set the custom Icon as the icon for the NotifyIcon
notifyIcon1.Icon = customIcon;
```

Comment: There are a lot of sample code like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379547/writing-text-to-the-system-tray-instead-of-an-icon

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing text to the system tray instead of an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379547/writing-text-to-the-system-tray-instead-of-an-icon)